# Local Frame and Transition Function of Complex Line Bundle on Torus

Tags: differential-geometry, group-actions, vector-bundles

I want to show the quotient $L:=\left(\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{C}\right) / \mathbb{Z}^2$ is a complex line bundle over $\mathbb{T}^2$. With the group action given by:
$$
(m, n) \cdot(x, y, z)=\left(x+m, y+n, e^{2 \pi i n x} z\right), \quad(m, n) \in \mathbb{Z}^2,(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{C}
$$
I want to find local frames and show that the transition function between local frame is holomorphic. My guess is that the local frame is something like this: $$e_U ([x,y]) = e^{2\pi i x}$$

Any suggestions (hint) on which chart and local frame should I construct here?

Comment: You shouldn't expect the given bundle to carry a natural holomorphic structure, since the $\mathbb{Z}^2$ action you exhibit is not holomorphic. The $z$ component of the action only depends on the $x$ value and not the $y$ value.

Comment: This also confuses me... It seems that the representation $\rho$ not only encodes an action $\mathbb{Z}^2$ on $\mathbb{C}$, but also depends on $x$ i.e. $\rho((m,n))(z) = e^{2\pi i nx} z$ is not a representation...

Comment: I only mention the $z$ component for the sake of understanding whether the map is holomorphic or not. Taking the components of a group action need not yield a group action in any meaningful sense.